# GVim keeps opening on the wrong workspace

Tags: gvim

I'm using KDE 5 with multiple desktops (in a 3x4 grid) and I regularly open Vim from the command line, e.g. with

```
gvim file.txt
```

The problem is when I do this, GVim often appears on a different desktop than the one I am currently focused on.  I then have to go and find it, and bring it on to the desktop I am working on.  This is inconvenient!

Some other curious details are:

- As well as opening on the wrong desktop, GVim is always at the *back* of the window list, so it's hidden behind other windows.
- (That actually helps me to find it.  I have a keybind to cycle windows on all desktops, and since GVim at the *far end* of the window list, I can find it quickly by cycling backwards.)
- I have not understood the pattern of which desktop GVim chooses to open on, however it seems to choose a recently used workspace, rather than one of the empty ones I rarely use.  On rare occasions, it does actually choose the desktop I am on!

Of all the applications I use, GVim is the only one with this behaviour.  How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again the other solutions are failing me.  So now I have a new workaround (for KDE 5):

- Right click on GVim's titlebar and select `More Actions > Configure Special Application Settings`
- Add the property `Virtual Desktop`
- Configure that to `Apply Initially` and `All Desktops`

  (also known as making the window "sticky")

This will guarantee the window appears on the current desktop.

However it does mean that after the window opens, I need to:

- Press my keyboard shortcut (or use window buttons) to remove the sticky / all-desktop flag from the window

---

Another problem I sometimes faced was that GVim was appearing behind all the other windows.

To fix that, I again went back to:

- `Configure Special Application Settings`
- And set `Focus stealing prevention:` `Force` `None`

Answer (score 1):

> Update: I thought this solution was working, but it isn't working for me now.
>
> It may be *part* of a solution.

This is probably a better solution, found from this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109696/gvim-always-opens-in-workspace-4

The **problem** may be caused by setting `lines` and/or `columns` from your `.vimrc`

The **workaround** is to move that setting into an autocommand.

```
" BAD.  Do not do this.
if has('gui_running')
    set lines=999 columns=999
endif

" GOOD.  Do this instead.
autocmd GUIEnter * :set lines=999 columns=999
```

---

However there was one other contributing factor:

- I had been running `gvim filename.txt &`

  (The reason is not really important, but: This was part of a script that can start many different editors, some of which do need to be run in the background.)

Using `&` to run in the background was causing problems.  GVim *sometimes* didn't like that it was disconnected from stdin.  Possibly due to some of the plugins I was running.  Perhaps Coc or ALE or Vim addon manager was trying to use stdin.

**Solution:**

- Don't use `&` to background the process when starting `gvim`

  Let `gvim` background itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Update: I thought this solution was working, but it isn't working now.

This seems like a rare issue, but I found a thread where people have a similar problem on a different window manager: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/2411

It seems like the **problem** is that GVim is making a geometry request that causes the window manager to place it on a different desktop.

A **workaround** is to tell the window manager to ignore GVim's geometry requests.

On KDE 5 that can be done with the following steps:

- Right click on GVim's titlebar and select `More Actions > Configure Special Application Settings`
- Add the property `Ignore Requested Geometry`
- Configure that to `Force` and `Yes`

Now save the settings.  The next time you start GVim, hopefully it will open on the desired desktop!

If you have a different window manager than KDE, you may be able to find a different way to "ignore geometry requests".  Hope this helps!